# Add page number on appendices env start page

Tags: pdftex, appendix, abnt

How to add the page number / change the page style of the initial appendix page?

I am using the follow code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{abntex2}
\usepackage{appendix}
    \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Apêndice}
    \renewcommand*\cftappendixname{\appendixname\enspace}

\begin{document}
     \begin{appendices}
     \appendixpage
     Other appendix pages...
     \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

I want to change the `\appendixpage` page style to add the page number that the top-right corner as the default class style pages. I am using the `pdftex`compilation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I suppose you mean the `appendices ` environment?

Comment: Yes, @Bernard. I had fix in the question.

Comment: I tried an extended version of your MWE by adding text before `\begin{appendices}` and no page numbers were shown. Please extend your MWE to show pages before the appendices with their numbering. I also tried to add in `\pagestyle{plain}` to get numbering but to no effect. What is the default class page style?

Comment: Before and after the `\appendixpage` I have the correct page number stamped. I didn't change the default page style of the class during my text but , when I needed to `includepdf` into my document using the same page style, I used `\thispagestyle{fancy}` as `\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}, ...`.